# Xamarin Fody error throwing while debugging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Can anyone please suggest, how to fix below error which comes while debug in Xamarin.

*The "PackageDefinitions" parameter is not supported by the "Fody.WeavingTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.*

Just updated fody version with latest updates but still throwing error while debugging.

Fody version: 2.1.2

[Fody Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlUNC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove these two lines located in `csproj` file.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\..\..\Solution1\Project1\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Solution1\Project1\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" />
```

mentioned in [Fody issue](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/362)